# Is there a complex query builder in Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

The **structure** of document is as follows:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Demographics", "parent" : 0 }
```

I want do like as follow:

```
pyList=list(db.collection.find({"parent":0},{"_id":1}))
colList=list(db.collection.find({"parent":$in:[pyList]},{"name":1}))
```

As i have achieved my requirement but I am sure even that this is not optimized.
Kindly direct me to any such framework of **mongodb** where I can write one **query** and my requirement will be achieved.

Please be gentle as I am newbie.

Comment: You did not include the code.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-python/blob/master/examples/twisted/websocket/echo/server.py with one of the client variants in the containing folder.

Comment: I found solution for that and now I have to change question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your definition of optimized.
If you mean "number of lines of code" then you might want to check the possibilities offered by [MongoDB's aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).

If you mean "memory and speed" optimization, I would not recommend using anything else but MongoDB's basic find command. The reason for this is that a well-indexed collection will always provide faster query results when compared with an aggregation command. From what I see in your code, the only change I would recommend is to make sure the "parent" key is also indexed.